# ObservableCollection<T> on xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions, imultivalueconverter

I'm currently working on a `CustomConverter` on WPF. Which is like a Generic convertion.

Reading on this [blog](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35416/Use-of-MarkupExtension-with-Converters-in-WPF), found a way to simplify the xaml.

So the converter looks like this:

```
public CustomConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter {

    public ParametersCollection Parameters { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if(Parameters == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        //Convertion Logic
        //...
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return new CustomConverter();
    }
}
public class ParametersCollection : ObservableCollection<object> {
}
```

And in my Xaml file, have the following:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                 xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                 xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:NS.Converters">
    <Label>
        <Label.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding>
                <converter:CustomConverter>
                    <converter:CustomConverter.Parameters>
                        <converter:ParametersCollection>
                            <primitives:String>Param1</primitives:String>
                            ...
                        </converter:ParametersCollection>
                    </converter:CustomConverter.Parameters>
                </converter:CustomConverter>
            </MultiBinding>
            <!--Bindings start here -->
        </Label.Visibility>
    </Label>
</UserControl>
```

So when debbuging the code, the `Parameters` property is empty (null), so the xaml is not populating the collection. So my question is, how to popultate Parameters by using only xaml, no C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint on the first line of your `Convert` method, you'll find that `Parameters` is always `null`. That's because you never initialize it. The solution is to initialize that property in the constructor (or right in the declaration, if you're in C#6).

`Parameters` doesn't need to be `ObservableCollection<T>`, because nobody will ever bind to it, and it doesn't need to be a non-generic subclass either. Lastly, `ProvideValue()` should provide the actual instance that has the `Parameters` you were given from the XAML. If you return a new instance with an empty `Parameters` collection, it won't have any `Parameters`. `ProvideValue()` is called after you're created and initialized. The purpose isn't to provide a new instance of your own class, but for markup extensions like `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` that take their parameters and use those to create or retrieve an instance of something other than themselves.

```
public class CustomConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public CustomConverter()
    {
        Parameters = new List<Object>();
    }
    public List<Object> Parameters { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Parameters == null)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        //  Just something that returns something, for testing
        //  Replace with your own convertion logic. 
        return String.Join(";", Parameters);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, The problem was taht the variable was not initialized.

Comment: @jcvegan Groovy!